# How not load a library into a entry point?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I'm developing a GWT application using Isomorphic's smartGWT tables. 
The problem is that I've got two entry points, one for the main application and one for a Chrome plugin.

The code of the plugin is very simple and don't need smartGWT however load it. The size of my plugin without smartGWT is 3kB, with smartGWT is 677KB.

If I remove the line that inherits the smartGWT library in the .gwt.xml file (`< inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" />` ) for my Chrome plugin the application doesn't compile and throws the following error:

> [ERROR] Line 18: No source code is available for type
>   com.smartgwt.client.data.DSResponse; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?

How I can not load the SmartGWT without the compiling error?

Comment: To be clear: you have a GWT application and  Chrome plugin in the same project, the GWT application uses SmartGWT, the plugin don't use it, but the application and the plugin share code?

Comment: Yes, both share code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to split your GWT project in three projects:

1. Project A: A GWT library With common code for GWT app and Chrome plugin, with no dependencies to SmartGWT
2. Project B: A GWT app with dependency to A module and SmartGWT.
3. Project C: a Chrome plugin with dependency to A module and no dependency to SmartGWT.

Comment: The problem is I need the app and the plugin in the same GAE Application, because both share the BBDD and also the plugin is an URL that calls the especific entry point in my application (e.g: the URL to enter my application is myapp.appspot.com and the plugin calls to myapp.appspot.com/Extension.jsp) further I can't use diferent versions in GAE because SSL connection doesn't work (e.g: myapp.appspot.com for the application and 2.myapp.appspot.com for the plugin).

Comment: So the plugin is a simply javascript that calls you GWT application?

Comment: Yes, the plugin calls my application indicating the entry point to run